# C# TCP server for receiving/storing information in a "friends list" from a client for a chat program

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, tcp, chat

I am seeking advice on making a TCP server which can store/receive the data from a friends list for a chat program. I don't have experience with databases, so I am attempting to write the information to a text file. For now I want to focus on storing username and password, but I am not completely sure how to do this. Another person on my team is creating the client, so I just need to have a server which can receive this information from the client and store it.

Comment: Are you asking "how to make a TCP server?". A tutorial would be appropriate for you.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx

Comment: I know how to make a TCP server, a fairly simple one anyhow. I am more specifically asking how to go about storing information on username and IP address for a chat program. I only have a vague idea on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For providing an interface where the client can store his data use WCF or better WebApi.
How the storage is implemented server-side should be of no concern from the client.

If it's just about chat, complement it with SignalR

No need to think about the difficulties over writing a multi-threaded server implementation over sockets while you are not ready for it (as I register from your post) WCF and webapi makes the tcp details almost transparent so you only have to think about the functionality required.

For persisting the data on the server I would go for a light-weighted solution in a No-Sql database.
Easy solution to adapt to the changing requirements. Espec since it seems that there is no real design(-document) in place. 
Later on you when the datamodel is more mature you can change to a SQL solution if the application (or management) requires it.

And take the modern standards about security into mind, like (for a starter) not storing password in clear text.